# Get list of areas in asp net core for staticFiles middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use dotnet core mvc (v3.0 preview) and use areas to separate mostly independent pages of the application. I would like to have my .js and .css files also stored in the areas folder, so I came up with the following in my `Startup.cs`:

```cs
            app.UseStaticFiles();// wwwroot
            var areas = new string[]{"Intro", "Todo"};
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions{
                FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider( areas.Select( area =>
                    new PhysicalFileProvider(
                        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"Areas", area, "wwwarearoot"))
                    ).ToArray()),
                RequestPath = "/areas",
                ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(
                    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    {
                        { ".js", "application/javascript" },
                        { ".css", "text/css"},
                    })
            });
```

This allows (requires) me to have js in the folders `Areas/Intro/wwwarearoot/` and `Areas/Todo/wwwarearoot/` and import javascript and css under the `~/areas/` prefix.

My question i about how to improve the second line, so I actually get the application areas, instead of having a static list.

Comment: Maybe this [Directory Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory?view=netframework-4.8) and [DirectoryInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8) could help. My idea is that you can get all directories inside `Areas` folder and get their names.

Comment: That's kind of the obvious answer looking back. I somehow got the wrong idea that folders aren't available runtime. I can even fix the error if wwwarearoot does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find code when I searched for this problem, here is the complete code I ended up with.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

namespace MyNamespace.Utils{
    public static class AppExtensions{
        private static IEnumerable<string> _GetAreasWithAreaRoot(){
            var cd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(cd, "Areas"));
            var areas = directory.EnumerateDirectories();
            foreach(var area in areas){
                var wwwarearoot = area.EnumerateDirectories("wwwarearoot").FirstOrDefault();
                if(wwwarearoot != null){
                    yield return wwwarearoot.FullName;
                }
            }
        }
        public static void UseAreaStaticFiles(this IApplicationBuilder app){
            var areas = _GetAreasWithAreaRoot();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions{
                FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider( areas.Select( areawwwroot =>
                    new PhysicalFileProvider(areawwwroot)
                ).ToArray()),
                RequestPath = "/areas",
                ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider(
                    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    {
                        { ".js", "application/javascript" },
                        { ".css", "text/css"}
                    })
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In my `Startup.cs` I can add

```cs
using MyNamespace.Utils;
...
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseAreaStaticFiles(); // Areas/{area}/wwwarearoot
    ...
}
```

To ensure that your wwwarearoot files gets included in your published artifacts, you might also want to add the following to your `*.csproj` file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Content Include="Areas\*\wwwarearoot\**">
         <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```